# spring-boot get a "400 bad request" error, the detail is followed

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc, spring-boot, http-headers

I am very new on spring boot. So the question I asked maybe cause by I
   missing something. I use spring boot 1.3 and freemarker to build a
   web site. when I submit a form( which some properties I don't fill in
   and this situation is I need) I get a "400 bad request". However,
   when I fill in all the properties of the form and submit, it works.
   So, what's the reason and How can I fix it?

The form is the following code.

```
    <label for="steelName" >品名:</label>
    <input type="text" id="steelName" name="steelName" placeholder="品名" value="${steelName!}" required><br/>

    <label for="steelCode" >钢种:</label>
    <input type="text" id="steelCode" name="steelCode" placeholder="钢种" value="${steelCode!}" required><br/>

    <label for="basic_price" >基价:</label>
    <input type="text" id="basicPrice" name="basicPrice" placeholder="2000" value="${basicPrice!}" required>
    <label>元</label><br/>

    <label for="steel_factory" >钢厂:</label>
    <input type="text" id="steelFactory" name="steelFactory" placeholder="钢厂名称" value="${steelFactory!}" >

    <label for="city" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;城市:</label>
    <input type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="城市" value="${city!}" >

    <br/>

    <label for="width" >宽度范围:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lowWidth" name="lowWidth" placeholder="1.0" value="${lowWidth!}" >
    <label for=""> - </label>
    <input type="text" id="highWidth" name="highWidth" placeholder="1.6" value="${highWidth!}" >
    <label for=""> m </label>

    <label for="width_step">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;宽度步长：</label>
    <input type="text" id="widthStep" name="widthStep" placeholder="1.0" value="${widthStep!}" >
    <label for=""> m </label>

    <label for="width_price">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;宽度差价：</label>
    <input type="text" id="widthPrice" name="widthPrice" placeholder="1.0" value="${widthPrice!}" >
    <label for=""> 元 </label>

    </br>

    <label for="thickness" >厚度范围:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lowThickness" name="lowThickness" placeholder="1.0" value="${lowThickness!}" >
    <label for=""> - </label>
    <input type="text" id="highThickness" name="highThickness" placeholder="1.6" value="${highThickness!}" >
    <label for=""> cm </label>

    <label for="thickness_step">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;厚度步长：</label>
    <input type="text" id="thicknessStep" name="thicknessStep" placeholder="1.0" value="${thicknessStep!}" >
    <label for=""> cm </label>

    <label for="thickness_price">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;厚度差价：</label>
    <input type="text" id="thicknessPrice" name="thicknessPrice" placeholder="1.0" value="${thicknessPrice!}" >
    <label for=""> 元 </label>

    </br>

    <button type="submit">提交</button>

</form>
```

The Controller.java

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/add/steel", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addSteel(@ModelAttribute("steel")Steel steel, Model model) {

    log.info("add "+steel.getSteelName()+" info.");
    //model.addAttribute(FormAuthenticationFilter.DEFAULT_USERNAME_PARAM, userName);
    steel = steelService.save(steel);
    model.addAttribute("steel", steel);
    return "steel/detail";
}
```

The steel entity

```
 @Entity
        @Table(name = "t_steel")
        public class Steel extends IdEntity {    
        @Column(name = "steel_name", unique = true)
        private String steelName;
        @Column(name = "steel_code", unique = true)
        private String steelCode;
        @Column(name = "basic_price", unique = true)
        private int basicPrice;

    @Column(name = "steel_factory", nullable = true)
    private String steelFactory = null;

    @Column(name = "city", nullable = true)
    private String city = null;

    @Column(name = "low_width", nullable = true)
    private Double lowWidth = null;

    @Column(name = "high_width", nullable = true)
    private Double highWidth  = null;

    @Column(name = "width_step", nullable = true)
    private Double widthStep  = null;

    @Column(name = "width_price", nullable = true)
    private Integer widthPrice  = null;
```

The question:

This is the link to [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPWSr.png)
This is the link to[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qv0yD.png)

Comment: Can you add the starting `<form>` tag?

Comment: <form name="steel" action="${base}/admin/add/steel" method="post">

Answer (score 32):

Add the following property to your spring boot configuration `logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG`. With such log level, you will have detailled error explaining the cause of the 400.

You could also drop a logback.xml in in your classpath (src/main/resources for exemple) and add this appender :

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG" />

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much! By your solution， I can find the reason due to "400 bad request", which is validation.BindException. The client-side entity  do not match the sever-side entity.

Comment: Give me also hint on how see what was the issue! Thanks @Daniel!

Answer (score 0):

Add below method in controller.java. it will give more detail error report in addition to 400 bad request. here apiError is my customized exception. you can give any user defined exception here.

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {MissingServletRequestParameterException.class})
    ApiError handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MissingServletRequestParameterException ex) {

        return new ApiError(ErrorCode.MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMS, ex.getMessage());
    }
```